# Lag before suspend

Tags: 16.04, networking, xubuntu, suspend

I have Lenovo ThinkPad 13 and Xubuntu 16.04 on it and I got annoyed by the time it usually takes to suspend the laptop (more than 5 seconds) after I hit the suspend button. I messed around a bit and I discovered that when wifi is off, suspend is instantaneous. Is there any way that I have both my wifi and quick suspend at the same time?

I tried pairing `nmcli radio all off && systemctl suspend` with no effect. But when I execute the first command, wait a little for the network to turn off and than the second one, the suspend works without the lag.

Comment: Maybe that's just how long it takes. If you run `nmcli radio all off` on its own does it take the same amount of time? So when you suspend, it turns off devices including the radio, taking 5 seconds (say). If the radio is already off, turning off devices takes almost no time. If you run `nmcli radio all off && systemctl suspend` it turns off radio taking ~ 5 seconds then suspends.

Comment: When I run `nmcli radio all off` on its own, the effect is instant (judging from the change of networking indicator icon). It's definitely not the >5 seconds that it takes to suspend the laptop. My guess is that suspend waits on some kind of timeout.

Comment: I also tried to run `systemctl --ignore-inhibitors suspend` but with no recognizable effect. Source: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/man1/systemctl.1.html

Comment: In your question you said "wait a little for the network to turn off" - isn't that saying that the network takes a little while to turn off, even when done separately from suspending?

Comment: Well, the waiting part was just a precaution. I'm not sure how to measure the time it takes for the networking to turn off in an exact way.

Comment: I just tried to execute the second command immediately after the first one and it worked, suspending right after I pressed enter on the second command. So i did `nmcli radio all off && sleep 1 && systemctl suspend` and the computer suspends in around that one second. The drawback is that the wifi is turned off on resume, but it seems to validate my initial hunch that the >5 seconds time for suspend is too long.